# nginx and try_files: try named location with rewrites before fallback

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I'm attempting a website cut-over. We want to preserve our external links by using 301 redirects. I have a lengthy list of redirects in a named location that resembles:

```
location @redirects {       
    rewrite ^/path/one.html$ http://www.ourdomain.tld/one-but-different permanent;
    rewrite ^/path/two.html$ http://www.ourdomain.tld/two-but-different permanent;
    rewrite ^/path/three.html$ http://www.ourdomain.tld/three-but-different permanent;
    rewrite ^/path/four.html$ http://www.ourdomain.tld/four-but-different permanent;
}
```

(please note that even though it appears that my example shows a pattern, no pattern exists. In other words they are one-to-one redirects.)

I have a CMS web application that I'm using the following try_files statement currently (which has been working all along for falling back to the index.php script):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

Now I'm attempting to use try_files to "look at" the redirects named location and processing the rewrite BEFORE falling back to index.php. Like this:

```
location / {
    try_files @redirects $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

However, the fallback is being triggered each time as the CMS is handling 404's. In other words, if I try http://www.ourdomain.tld/path/one.html, I get the 404 page for my CMS instead of a redirect! Is it possible to "try" a named location first or does the named location have to be the fallback?

I'm sure I'm doing this wrong. However, can someone point me in the right direction?

nginx/1.2.4

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I can just throw my redirects into the server directive but I'd prefer to keep them in a named location if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the documentation: http://nginx.org/r/try_files ? `try_files` does not try locations, it tries files.

Comment: I guess that answers my question. Thanks @VBart. That makes impeccable sense. I suppose I need to stick it in the server block after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right way is:

```
location = /path/one.html {
    return 301 http://www.ourdomain.tld/one-but-different;
}

location = /path/two.html {
    return 301 http://www.ourdomain.tld/two-but-different;
}

etc...
```

Please, avoid to use rewrites if possible. Nginx isn't Apache. URL rewriting is an inefficient and tricky way of configuring web server. Nginx prefers URL-mapping. The `location` prefix matching is very fast and efficient.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/

--

In the case of a very large number (500+) of redirects:

```
map $uri $redirect_to {
    include /path/to/redirects.map;
}

server {
    location / {
        if ($redirect_to) {
             return 301 http://www.ourdomain.tld$redirect_to;
        }
    }
}
```

**redirects.map:**

```
/path/one.html /one-but-different;
/path/two.html /two-but-different;
etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen this answer before and tried to avoid it because I have about 1000 of these redirects. I own several good text editors and I'm proficient with regular expressions, however, I just wanted to avoid all the extra characters. And I come from a long-time Apache background! LOL. Thanks again!

Comment: If you have ~1000 redirects, then probably the `map` directive will be more efficient. Note, it has the `include` parameter that can be very useful in your case. http://nginx.org/r/map

Answer (score 2):

Another way you can do this is with a [map](http://nginx.org/r/map).

An example; off the top of my head so check for syntax errors first...:

```
map $uri $new {
  /path/one.html http://www.example.com/new_path_one;
  /path/two.html http://www.example.com/new_path_two;
}

server {
  if ($new) {
    return 301 $new;
  }
  ....
}
```

Comment: I saw vbart's response first. Must have just missed your answer here. Thanks. I was actually just looking for how to implement. 

Would you humor me by explaining what $new is? $uri is the current request URI. But $new is undocumented. Just wondering how nginx determines that it should substitute $new for the $uri when $new is true???

Comment: `$uri` is set by nginx to the request URI. `$new` is any variable name you want. `$new` is set to the corresponding value when `$uri` matches one of the patterns given (you can also use regexes here).

Comment: Okay, so how on earth does if ($new){... work? Does the hash map work both directions?

Comment: If `$new` was set to a value by the map, then the `return` statement gets executed. If the map didn't match anything, then `$new` will not be set, and the `return` will not happen.